# The pd.DataFrame.replace() function is not working

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I simply want to change a value in my dataframe (using pandas) with another. I tried the df.replace() function but with any success.
This is my code:

```
ID   species         Gene
1    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 1
2    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 2
3    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 5
4    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 3

df.replace(to_replace='NADH', value='NAD')

print(df)

ID   species         Gene
1    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 1
2    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 2
3    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 5
4    Genus_species   NADH dehydrogenase subunit 3
```

Anything changes.
Is it my command correct or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use: `df.replace(to_replace='NADH', value='NAD', regex=True)`

Comment: `replace` searches for exact match of columns so it does not work. What you needed to do was write regex in replace like `df.replace("NADH","NAD",regex=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do so:

```
df["Gene"] = df["Gene"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('NADH', 'NAD')) 
print(df)
#   ID        species                         Gene
#0   1  Genus_species  NAD dehydrogenase subunit 1
#1   2  Genus_species  NAD dehydrogenase subunit 2
#2   3  Genus_species  NAD dehydrogenase subunit 5
#3   4  Genus_species  NAD dehydrogenase subunit 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` is what I usually go for a *specific column*:

```
df["Gene"] = df["Gene"].str.replace('NADH', 'NAD'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["Gene"] = df["Gene"].replace("NADH","NAD",regex=True)
```

the regex=True argument makes sure it also looks inside the string value.

Answer (score 1):

Your almost there. All you need to add is either of these

```
inplace=True
regex=True

df.replace(to_replace='NADH', value='NAD', inplace=True)
df.replace(to_replace='NADH', value='NAD', regex=True)
```